# Alfred takes longer to show results, database disk image is malformed

Tags: macos, alfred

I don't know why, but about a week ago I started seeing a lot of errors like this in system.log:

```
9/15/12 5:55:21.769 AM Alfred[263]: DB Query: select item, count(item) as used from knowledge where ts > ? and item in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) group by item
9/15/12 5:55:21.769 AM Alfred[263]: DB Error: 11 "database disk image is malformed"
```

It would occasionally take about a second for files to show up in the result list.

Deleting the Spotlight index didn't help, but then I noticed that the usage tab didn't display any statistics either:

[image]

I think I solved it by just pressing the reset knowledge button. But I didn't find search results for this issue, so I'm answering this question myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, pressing the reset knowledge button in the preferences seems to have fixed it.

If you get similar errors, you could also try removing `~/Library/Application Support/Alfred/knowledge.alfdb` or other database files. If you're using a sandboxed version bought from the App Store, they are in `~/Library/Containers/com.alfredapp.Alfred/Data/`.